# SQL assessment query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck with the following queries.

1. Show the full name and the phone number of the customer who made the most orders.
2. Which item is the best seller? Display description and price.

Attached is my ERD.

```
create table statements are as follows:
CREATE TABLE ITEMS (
itemID number(5),
itemDescription varchar2(60),
itemSize varchar2(22),       
itemColour varchar2(10),
itemPrice number (5,2),
itemQuantityAvailable number(3),
CONSTRAINT pk_items PRIMARY KEY (itemID));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
custID number(5),
custLName varchar2(10),
custFName varchar2(20),
custAddress varchar2(30),
custTown varchar2(20),
custPostcode number(4),
custPhone number(10),
custEmail varchar2(30),
shopID number(5),
CONSTRAINT pk_customers PRIMARY KEY (custID),
CONSTRAINT fk_customers_shopID FOREIGN KEY (shopID)
REFERENCES SHOPS (shopID));

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
orderNo number(5),
orderDate Date,
dispatchDate date,
custID number(5),
CONSTRAINT pk_orders PRIMARY KEY (orderNo),
CONSTRAINT fk_orders_custID FOREIGN KEY (custID)
REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (custID));

CREATE TABLE OrderQuantity (
orderNo number(5),
itemID number(5),
orderQuantity number(3),
CONSTRAINT pk_orderQty PRIMARY KEY (itemID, orderNo),
CONSTRAINT fk_orderQty_itemID FOREIGN KEY (itemID)
REFERENCES ITEMS (itemID),
CONSTRAINT fk_orderQty_orderNo FOREIGN KEY (orderNO)
REFERENCES ORDERS (orderNo));
```

INSERT STATEMENTS ARE AS FOLLOWS:

```
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (1,'ADIDAS MEN''S ID STADIUM FULL-ZIP JACKET','S/M/L/XL','Silver',89.99,100);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (2,'ADIDAS MEN''S ESSENTIALS 3 STRIPES CREW FRENCH TERRY','S/L/XL','Black',71.99,90);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (3,'ADIDAS MEN''s ESSENTIALS 3-STRIPES FLEECE PANT','M/L/XL/XXL','White',62.99,80);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (4,'NIKE MEN''S FULL-ZIP SPORTSWEAR HOODIE','M/L/XL','DarkGrey',67.49,70);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (5,'NIKE MEN''S HBR FLEECE CREW','S/L/XL','DarkGrey',58.49,60);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (6,'PUMA MEN''S ESSENTIAL SWEAT PANTS','XS/S/M/L/XL','Navy',45.00,50);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (7,'ADIDAS MEN''S ESSENTIALS CHELSEA SHORTS','M/L/XL','Green',35.99,40);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (8,'PUMA MEN''S CORE 7IN RUNNING SHORTS','S/L/XL','Black',26.99,20);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (9,'ASICS GT 2000 6 MEN''S RUNNING SHOES','8/8.5/9/9.5/10','Silver',239.00,90);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (10,'ASICS GEL-KAYANO 25 2E WIDE MEN''S RUNNING SHOE','9/9.5/10/10.5/11','Black',219.00,60);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (11,'REEBOK RUNNER 3.0 MEN''S RUNNING SHOES','8/8.5/10/10.5','Orange',209.00,10);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (12,'REEBOK MEN''S WORKOUT READY 2.0 TEE','XS/S/M','White',199.00,50);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (13,'UNDER ARMOUR RAPID MEN''S RUNNING SHOES','8.5/10/11','Black',199.00,20);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (14,'UNDER ARMOUR CHARGED MEN''S RUNNING SHOES','8/8.5/9/9.5/10','Silver',159.00,80);
INSERT INTO ITEMS VALUES (15,'ADIDAS SOLAR DRIVE MEN''S RUNNING SHOE','8/8.5/10/10.5','Black',139.00,30);


INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (1,'Widimer','Cindy','121 King St','Box Hill',3195,0470121566,'cindy_widimer@gmail.com',1);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (2,'Bohrman','Robert','54 Queens St','Murrumbeena',3195,0455131565,'robert_bohram@gmail.com',3);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (3,'Clarke','Brenda','89 Pecket St','Oakleigh',3195,0424456123,'brenda.clarke@gmail.com',2);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (4,'Cartier','Bruce','12 Parkore St','Mulgrave',3195,0425654123,'bruce.cartier@gmail.com',3);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (5,'Heart','Lucy','45 Rose St','Hampton Park',3178,0470456321,'lucy.heart@gmail.com',1);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (6,'Carter','Joan','123 Davdison St','Hampton Park',3178,0452123789,'carter_joangmail.com',3);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (7,'John','Ailene','56 Spring St','Yaraman',3178,0475123159,'john.ailene@gmail.com',1);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (8,'Lewis','Carl','45 Brendon Ct','Noble Park',3178,0454789456,'carl_lewis@gmail.com',3);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (9,'Holden','Hilary','56 Swanston St','Sunshine',3020,0421456123,'hilar_holdengmail.com',1);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (10,'Powell','Venus','124 Russel St','Richmond',3112,0431456753,'venus_powellgmail.com',2);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (11,'Juliet','Susan','87 Fawkner Ct','South Yara',3141,0424687423,'susan_juliet@gmail.com',2);
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES (12,'Price','Victor','125 William St','Flagstaff',3003,0465789123,'victor_price@gmail.com',2);


INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (1,'01/Jan/18','03/Feb/18',1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (2,'20/Jan/18','05/Feb/18',3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (3,'05/Feb/18','10/Feb/18',4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (4,'18/Feb/18','22/Feb/18',5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (5,'01/Mar/18','10/Mar/18',10);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (6,'12/Mar/18','15/Mar/18',12);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (7,'07/Apr/18','14/Apr/18',11);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (8,'25/Apr/18','27/Apr/18',3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (9,'06/May/18','10/May/18',2);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (10,'17/Jun/18','20/Jun/18',5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (11,'29/Jun/18','07/Jul/18',4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (12,'08/Jul/18','14/Jul/18',11);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (13,'25/Jul/18','29/Jul/18',12);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (14,'01/Aug/18','18/Aug/18',5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (15,'19/Aug/18','10/Sep/18',1);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (16,'11/Sep/18','15/Sep/18',4);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (17,'21/Sep/18','29/Sep/18',5);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (18,'01/Oct/18',null,10);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (19,'20/Oct/18',null,3);
INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (20,'23/Oct/18',null,1);

INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (1,1,20);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (2,3,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (3,4,20);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (4,5,14);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (5,10,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (6,11,15);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (7,12,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (8,3,25);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (9,2,50);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (10,5,20);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (11,4,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (12,11,20);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (13,12,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (14,5,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (15,1,10);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (16,4,30);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (17,5,9);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (18,10,30);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (19,3,20);
INSERT INTO OrderQuantity VALUES (20,1,15);
```

Comment: your group by clause should be ' c.custid, custfname||' '||custlname'

Comment: also, each customer will only have one count of orders, so doing a max on that doesn't make sense

Comment: Sample data would really help (`create table`,`insert` etc). Otherwise it's a lot of work for anyone to even start.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your query.

You can't use aggregate functions in the GROUP BY part of the SQL statement. 
Also, the MAX(COUNT(..... is clearly wrong.

When you need to extract "aggregate of the aggregate" the best way is to use "in-line views" (in Oracle terminology).

E.g. something like this:

```
 SELECT c.custid AS custid
      ,custfname||' '||custlname AS cust_fullname
      ,custPhone
      ,num_orders
  FROM customers c
      ,(SELECT custid, num_orders
          FROM (
                SELECT custid,count(*) as num_orders
                  FROM orders
              GROUP BY custid
              ORDER BY 2 desc
          ) all_orders
        WHERE ROWNUM<=1) largest_order
WHERE c.custid=largest_order.custid
```

Track the query from inside out e.g. from most inner (or indented) part.

```
        SELECT custid,count(*) as num_orders
          FROM orders
        GROUP BY custid
        ORDER BY 2 desc
```

Extracts the number of orders per custid for all custid, sorts it descending by the number.

```
SELECT custid, num_orders
      FROM (
            SELECT custid,count(*) as num_orders
              FROM orders
          GROUP BY custid
          ORDER BY 2 desc
      ) all_orders
    WHERE ROWNUM<=1
```

This ROWNUM stuff is the Oracle's way of selecting the first row of the results - "Oracle's LIMIT clause". Some other DBs could do it somewhat simpler.

The final query then just joins the result of the above with customers table to extract the full name and phone number.

There are several other ways to do it - mostly involving subqueries etc.. but this way is usually the fastest and I think is the most comprehensive.

Comment: Current Oracle versions also support the standard `fetch first n rows` - using rownum for this is no longer needed

Comment: Yes, but I don"t know what oracle version is used here, and ROWNUM works in every version